# stdio error detection: ferror versus fclose

Tags: c, language-lawyer, stdio

In standard C, how do you reliably check whether all output that was written to a standard I/O stream was successfully saved to disk?

The C standard states that `fclose` will return 0 on success, or EOF if "any errors were detected".

But does that mean "any errors were detected during the `fclose` call"?  Or does it mean "any errors were detected since the last call to `clearerr`"?

In other words, is it sufficient for a program to *just* check the return value of `fclose`, or is it also necessary to check `ferror`?  Are there any implementations where, if `ferror` returns non-zero, a subsequent call to `fclose` might return 0?

The same goes for `fflush`: is it always the case that if `fflush` returns 0, a subsequent call to `ferror` will also return 0, and if `fflush` returns EOF, a subsequent call to `ferror` will return non-zero?  Are there any implementations for which this is not the case?

(Of course, I'm not considering power outages, gremlins, etc.  Yes, a program that requires guaranteed durability should use `fsync`, but that's outside the scope of standard C.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of a better answer:

- the Standard tells me that `ferror()` returns the state of the 'error indicator' which is defined to be part of the *stream* state.
- the Standard tells me a lot about when the 'error indicator' is set, but nothing about when it may be cleared -- except that `clearerr()` and `rewind()` *are* defined to clear it.
- the Standard tells me nothing about what any function (other than `ferror()`) is expected to do if the 'error indicator' is set when the function is called.

Your questions seem to be based on the possibility that the 'error indicator' is set as soon as there is an error and only cleared when explicitly cleared (it is "latched").  In which case:

1. `ferror()` would tell you that an error has occurred in some stdio function, since the `fopen()` (or the most recent `clearerr()` or `rewind()`).

   I don't think the Standard requires that, but it doesn't say it may not.
2. `fclose()` might return an error (a) if one occurs while closing, *or* (b) if the 'error indicator' was already set.

   And, if so, a successful `fclose()` would mean that all was and has been well, since the `fopen()` (or the most recent `clearerr()` or `rewind()`).

   I don't think the Standard requires that, but it doesn't say it may not.

Where the Standard does not explicitly require something and does not explicitly rule something out, we have ourselves a cat which is neither alive nor dead.

In short, I don't think the Standard answers any of your questions, one way or another.

A conservative reading of the standard would be:

- to check for errors immediately after every stdio function call, and proceed accordingly.
- in general, after a read or write error, giving up and closing the stream is the obvious response.

  `fclose()` may return the current error (again), or a new error or no error at all.  Where an error is to be returned I would return the original read/write error.  Where errors are to be reported I would report both the original read/write error and any error returned by `fclose()`.
- if the decision is to keep on inputting/outputting, the 'error indicator' may (or may not) affect further functions, and may (or may not) be cleared by most further functions...

  ... so it is probably best to clearerr(), to avoid any possible confusion.

  However, I am almost convinced that `fgetc()` must either:

  a. give up immediately if 'error indicator' is already set (and set `errno`, again)

  or:

  b. clear 'error indicator' -- for if not, what does it mean if `fgetc()` then succeeds and returns `EOF` ?

  The same is true of the other get and put char and wide-char.  Not quite so true of all the other functions, where the return value is not ambiguous.
- to not expect `ferror()` to tell you anything about errors which may have happened before the most recent stdio function call.

  It is clear that `ferror()` is useful for those few functions where the error return is the same as an `EOF` or `WEOF` return.  (And `feof()` is useful if it is possible that a character with the value `EOF` or `WEOF` may appear !).

  It is less clear whether `ferror()` and the 'error indicator' are useful for anything else.

---

**FWIW: what I found in the Standard**

The Standard says (§7.21.7.1) that for `fgetc()`:

> 2. If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a next character is present, the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an unsigned char converted to an int and advances the associated file position indicator for the stream (if defined).
>
> Returns
>
> 3. If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`. Otherwise, the `fgetc` function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by stream. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF` <sup>*293)*</sup>.
>
> *<sup>293)</sup> An end-of-file and a read error can be distinguished by use of the `feof` and `ferror` functions.*

I note that this is very clear on what it should do if the 'end-of-file indicator' is set when the function is called.  In contrast, it does not say, one way or another, what `fgetc()` should do if the 'error indicator' is already set:

1. should `fgetc()` fail immediately ?

   If so, should it set `errno` to the same value as when the 'error indicator' was first set ?

   However, if the 'error indicator' were previously set by (say) `EINTR`, it would make no sense to take any notice of it.

otherwise:

2. should `fgetc()` clear the 'error indicator' if this call succeeds ?

   If not, then 'error indicator' could be deemed to be a "latched" state, indicating that at some time since it was last cleared, an error has occurred.

   Again, if the 'error indicator' were previously set by (say) `EINTR`, it would make no sense to leave it set.  Mind you, C knows nothing of `EINTR`... so the implementation is free to do different things with the 'error indicator', depending on how it was set.

   *AND*, if `fgetc()` just happens to fetch a character with value `EOF` or just happens to hit actual EOF, then *NOT* clearing the 'error indicator' would be a mistake !

The Standard says (§7.21.7.3) that for `fputc()`:

> 2. The `fputc` function writes the character specified by `c` (converted to an unsigned char) to the output stream ...
>
> Returns
>
> 3. The `fputc` function returns the character written. If a write error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and `fputc` returns `EOF`.

And again, this does not specify what `fputc()` should do if the 'error indicator' is already set.

And the same applies to `fgetwc()` and `fputwc()`.

Every other input/output function is defined to work "as if" they are repeated `fgetc()`, `fputc()`, `fgetwc()` and fputwc()`.

The Standard says (§7.21.10.3) that for `ferror()`:

> 2. The `ferror` function tests the error indicator for the stream pointed to by stream.
>
> Returns
>
> 3. The `ferror` function returns nonzero if and only if the error indicator is set for stream.

That's it.  Footnote *293* above is the most concrete guide we have for how `ferror()` and the 'error indicator' should be used.

`fflush()` (§7.21.5.2), `fseek()` (§7.21.9.2) and `fsetpos()` (§7.21.9.3) are all defined to set the 'error indicator' in the event of an error.

`rewind()` (§7.21.9.5) and `clearerr()` (§7.21.10.1) are defined to clear the 'error indicator'.

I found no other references to the 'error indicator'.